# Dreamweaver CS6 Login Server Behaviour does not work on production server

Tags: php, session, dreamweaver

Many thanks for reading.
I have used  the following code, generated by DW CS 6.0 - Login User ServerBehaviour - , to develop a password protected site with two user groups i.e. user and admin. The site is for demonstration purposes only ( Since DW produces PHP - MYSQL code which is obsolete - no PDO or MySQLi)

Code for DB connection:

```
$hostname_imerida = "xxxxx";
$database_imerida = "xxxxx";
$username_imerida = "xxxxx";
$password_imerida = "xxxxx";
$imerida = mysql_pconnect($hostname_imerida, $username_imerida, $password_imerida) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$imerida);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');`
```

Code generated by DW to login to the site if credentials are correct:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();

}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "role";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "managepub.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "index.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = true;
  mysql_select_db($database_imerida, $imerida);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password, role FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s",
  GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $imerida) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);


  if ($loginFoundUser) {

    $loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'role');

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
   $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
   $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;  

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
```

Code snippet that checks  (in this case) if admin is logged in and if not, it
forces a logout from the page that you try to access:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "admin";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 

  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "index.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);

  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
```

Site works great on localhost (XAMPP 1.7.7 [PHP: 5.3.8] ).
In the production enviroment (Linux with PHP Version 5.3.3) either needs two or three or four tries with correct password to login or (assuming that you are logged in as admin) after you log in and try to access a page it redirects you again to the initial page to enter the credentials again (please use as a reference the following)

```
$MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);

  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo);
```

Experiments showed that if I comment out the
`if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}`
the problem in the production server is eased and is very less often. This points me to the direction that
something is wrong with the sessions handling in the server but I can not come up with what I should do next or why this is happening.

Please share any ideas that you might have.

Many thanks.

Comment: You can find when session cookie is changed and why by debugging network headers, for example with Chrome (F12)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will use firebug but I am not fully aware on how this info will help me solve the problem.

Comment: For example the cookie is not set because some information was sent before setting the cookie. In this case you will find no cookie header.

Comment: Or the cookie is reset when it should not.

Comment: Thanks again Keiv.fly but shouldn't this problem happen in both localhost and production ( assuming something was sent before the header - for example a space character etc) since the script is the same?

Comment: I don't know whats the problem but you can find it. Find when the header is wrong. Then find the line in code that does it. And then I can really help you or you can help yourself.

Comment: cookies can have different expiration time

Comment: Or the query to database fails

Comment: Hi again , just a couple of notes. Database works OK (there is die(error message) as well). And the session id is being kept among pages redirects. One thing I have noticed though is that when I ask for a page in localhost it is returned but in the production I get for 1 or 2 times a 302 Moved Temporarily response instead of 200 OK. I have used the header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); after the  header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess ); to try to force a 200OK but with no success. Any ideas are truly welcome.

Comment: Check the settings of Apache server and the .htaccess file in the directory of requested file.

Comment: It is most likely that in production server you have settings that redirect the request to another page. For example, all the adresses without www are redirected to  www.site.com/index.html whatever the request was. You should find what adresses are being redirected. Find it in server configuration and change it.

Comment: I will give that a try by informing the provider. Thanks again for sharing your ideas.

Comment: There was a problem with the session handling from the provider. The code is working again. Many thanks.

Comment: I have rewritten our comments as an answer so you could accept. It may also be helpful for others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advised to debug network headers (F12 in Chrome) and see what the problem is.

It appeared that on production server occasionally there were strange redirect responses from the server.

I advised to look at the Apache configuration files. In the case of OP the hosting provider was responsible for Apache configuration. The OP contacted the hosting provider and solved his problem. There were problems with session management on the side of the hosting provider.

Comment: Although the problem was with session management from the hosting provider, I accepted the answer since the useful comments of keiv.fly pointed to a correct direction.